# Deploy Oozie jobs via Jenkins

Tags: hadoop, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, oozie

I am writing Oozie jobs and I want to deploy them to a hadoop cluster.

However rather than doing them manually, I want to use Jenkins to do this deployment for me.

I searched the web and didn't find any plugin for oozie .... so if you are using oozie on a hadoop cluster, can you please tell me what is the best way in which I could do automated build & deployments using Jenkins?

Comment: Have you searched for anything other than Jenkins plugins? Does Apache Oozie have an API that you could use? Have others already written API clients?

Comment: There is a REST API for Oozie.

Comment: Did you find any advantage of using Jenkins instead of oozie rest API for your requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deployment of Oozie workflows is just putting xml files and required dependencies not available on the cluster to HDFS directory. [link](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a7_Workflow_Application_Deployment)

- Assuming that you have two Jenkins jobs,

  - one for build, test etc
  - second for deployment which is triggered after sucesful build of first job

you can script putting files on HDFS in this second job for example using [WebHdfs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html)

Other way if product of your build from first job is some kind of a package e.g. zip, you can create a script which will download this artifact from Jenkins/Nexus to machine with access to hdfs console command, extract this zip and just put whole directory to hdfs, as its described  [here](https://github.com/jrkinley/oozie-examples)

If you are using some provisioning tool (Puppet or Ansible) you can use it for this purpose.

For configuring Jenkins scheduling you may want to use

- Jenkins [Pipeline Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md)
- or on Jenkins Job page "Configure -> Build Triggers -> Build after other projects are built"